# Convert string to IInputStream in C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a better way to implement conversion from a regular (large) string to [IInputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream) than this:

```cs
public static async Task<IInputStream> ToInputStream(this string input)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    var memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await memoryStream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
    await memoryStream.FlushAsync();
    memoryStream.Seek(0);

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, looks like there is a bit shorter version:

```
public static IInputStream ToInputStream(this string input)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    return stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Chris Guzak here is another version, based on `DataWriter.WriteString()`:

```
public async static Task<IInputStream> ToInputStreamAsync(this string input)
{
    var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    using(var dw = new DataWriter(ms))
    {
        dw.WriteString(input);
        await dw.StoreAsync();
        dw.DetachStream();
    }

    return ms;
}
```

Although not sure which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

DataWriter.WriteString() can be used for this. It writes the value in a specific format so check to make sure this is what you want.